# Real random variable $X$ such that $ \lim_{n\to \infty}{nP(|X|>n)}=0$ what about $ E|X|<\infty$?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

Let $X\colon (\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)\to (\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ be a random variable from a probability space to the real numbers with the Borel sets.

I proved that if $\mathbb  E|X|<\infty$ then $ \lim_{n\to \infty}{n\mathbb P(|X|>n)}=0$.

I want to know if the reciprocal is true or not. If not, I'd like to know if there are some extra hypothesis that can assure me that it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is NO.
There exists a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \mathbb{P}[X > n] = 0$ but $\mathbb{E}[X] = \infty$.

(The basic observation is simply the fact that $\int_{n_0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x \ln(x)}$ is divergent.)

Define the distribution such that $\mathbb{P}[X \leq n_0] = 0$ for some $n_0  > 0$, and $\mathbb{P}[X > n] = \frac{C}{n \ln(n)}$ for all $n > n_0$.
For such $\mathbb{P}$ it holds that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{n_0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[X > n] dn = \int_{n_0}^{\infty}  \frac{C}{n \ln(n)} = \ln\ln(n)|_{n_0}^\infty = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you cannot do better than: $\Bbb E |X| < \infty$ if and only if $\sum P(|X| > n) < \infty$. The proof is that these two quantities are actually *equal*,
$$
\Bbb E(|X|) = \sum_n \Bbb P(|X| > n).
$$

1. Consequence: if there is some $\alpha > 1$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^\alpha\, \Bbb P(|X| > n) = 0$, then $\Bbb E|X| < \infty$.
2. It is easy to find counter-examples if $\alpha = 1$. For instance, consider a random variable $X$  with distribution
   $$
   \Bbb P(X = n) = \frac{2\ln 2}{n\ln n} - \frac{2\ln 2}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}, \qquad n \geq 2
   $$
   and conclude with the fact that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n} = +\infty$.

Comment: I proved the following $E|X| \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{P(|X|>n)} \le E|X|+1$ But that's enough for the convergence. I want to know how you concluded your first consequence in the case $\alpha>1$ please I want to know

Comment: @Shanks, if $\alpha > 1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-\alpha} < \infty$.

Comment: Yes, but what series test are you using?

Comment: I know that the series of $n^{-\alpha}$ converges I'm talking the other conclusion